# show result in table with xquery

Tags: xquery

i have this xml

```
<Edu>
 <Department>
  <Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.aa</first_name>
  <last_name>bb</last_name>
</Profesor>

<Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.cc</first_name>
  <last_name>dd</last_name>
</Profesor>

<Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.ee</first_name>
  <last_name>ff</last_name>
</Profesor>
</Department>
<Course>
<name>programing</name>
<mosbat>4</mosbat>
<Class>1234</Class>
<Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.aa</first_name>
  <last_name>bb</last_name>
</Profesor>
<time>12:30:00</time>
<Student>
    <name>jack</name>
    <Std_ID>12345678</Std_ID>
    <Degree>MS</Degree>
</Student>

<Student>
  <name>parisa</name>
  <Std_id>54321876</Std_id>
  <Degree>BS</Degree>
</Student> 
</Course>
<Course>
<name>network</name>
<mosbat>9</mosbat>
<Class>6789</Class>
<Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.ee</first_name>
  <last_name>ff</last_name>
</Profesor>
<time>09:30:00</time>
<Student>
  <name>jack</name>
  <Std_ID>12345678</Std_ID>
  <Degree>MS</Degree>
</Student>
</Course>
<Course>
<name>Database</name>
<mosbat>3</mosbat>
<Class>4321</Class>
<Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.cc</first_name>
  <last_name>dd</last_name>
</Profesor>
<time>10:30:00</time>

<Student>
    <name>jack</name>
    <Std_ID>12345678</Std_ID>
    <Degree>MS</Degree>
</Student>

<Student>
    <name>caty</name>
    <Std_ID>87654321</Std_ID>
    <Degree>MS</Degree>
</Student> 
</Course>
<Course>
<name>data</name>
<mosbat>8</mosbat>
<Class>2341</Class>
<Profesor>
  <first_name>Dr.aa</first_name>
  <last_name>bb</last_name>
</Profesor>
<time>11:30:00</time>

  <Student>
    <name>jack</name>
    <Std_ID>12345678</Std_ID>
    <Degree>MS</Degree>
  </Student>

  <Student>
    <name>caty</name>
    <Std_ID>87654321</Std_ID>
    <Degree>MS</Degree>
  </Student>   
</Course>
</Edu>
```

and i want to have a table for each profesor that the first row of table is profesor name,and the second row is information about courses that profesor has. and remain rows of table are value for each field. i have this xquery,but it just draw table with 2 row, and value of each fields are empty
and my xquery is:

```
for $r in doc("XMLFile_Q2.xml")/Edu/Department/Profesor
 return
  <table  border="2" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <th>{$r[first_name and last_name]}</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
<th>course name</th>
<th>class</th>
<th>capacity</th>
<th>time</th>
<th>student</th>
  </tr>
  {for $a in doc("XMLFile_Q2.xml")/Edu/Department/Course
where $a/Profesor[first_name and last_name]=$r[first_name and last_name]
return
 <tr>
    <td>{$a/name/text()}</td>
    <td>{$a/Class/text()}</td>
    <td>{$a/mosbat/text()}</td>
    <td>{$a/time/text()}</td>
    <td>{$a/Student/name/text()}</td>

  </tr>}
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your XQuery:

```
for $a in doc("XMLFile_Q2.xml")/Edu/Department/Course
```

should be

```
for $a in doc("XMLFile_Q2.xml")/Edu/Course
```

(either that, or your file has the wrong format of course)

Comment: yes,you are right.i make mistake. thanks a lot.this small problem takes a lot of my time.